# Showing featured results with Elastic Search

Tags: php, sorting, pagination, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm using Elastic Search on PHP using Elastica.

I am retrieving a list which is composed of items. Some items are paid and/or chosen by the editors. Currently, I just sort them via a custom field 'score', which ranks these items based on their quality. I want a way to show 5 random listings by default (only when they haven't searched or filtered) at the top which are paid and chosed by the editors.

So what I'm currently doing is retrieving these 5 listings using a [custom filter score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query.html), setting the script to use random(). On a separate query that just sorts by score, I exclude those 5 listings. My problem is of course pagination and it just seems like a hack to use two queries and excluding the results of one query from the other for this purpose.

I have something like this:

```
{
    "custom_filters_score" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filters" : [
            ...
        ],
        "script" : "random()"
    }
}
```

So my question is, what's the easiest way to do this? I've seen function score, not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with Elastica, I've never used it. But in ElasticSearch, you want to use the [random_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html) function with a seed value that will stay consistent with pagination. That way you can be certain not to get the same results multiple times on different pages.

Comment: Hmm..I can't find the part where I determine the 'level' on which to apply randomness. But in my case, I want to apply it on a query with a different filter (being paid and editor's choice), is it possible to use random_score?

Comment: So, the query that you're using custom_filters_score was actually replaced by the function_score query. If you look at the docs for that (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) you'll notice that you have a ```query/filter``` component and a ```functions``` component. So you can add your filter as normal, and then ```random_score``` is one of the functions to be added to the ```functions``` array.